# Hoster blocking php config changes?

Tags: php, hosting, ini-set

my client gave me access to the shared hosting (that he chose and paid) for a website I'm doing. PHP is running as CGI. I can't change PHP settings through ini_set at all! Is this possible? Is this a standard practice of shared hosting?
What I basically need to do is to JUST activate errors! How can they expect someone to work with blank pages as "errors"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless they've seriously locked down settings:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

should be all you need.

Comment: @Sandro: Install WAMP/MAMP on your local machine and do your development locally. You could also have your client request that his hosting settings be changed to allow error reporting.